# setState not updating when called from inside a funciton

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with an onSubmit event calling a function. When I call the handleAddComment method from inside the handleSubmit function the state is not updated even though the method builds the object correctly in my console. The setState method is never run. When i call handleAddComment from the onSubmit event on the form everything works great. What am i missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/chrischilcoat/fqs02pvk/

```
const Reply = props => {
    const handleSubmit = e => { 
      handleAddComment();
      handleToggleReplyInput();
      e.preventDefault();
    };
    return (
      <ul className="ml-11" id={'reply-lvl-1-'+props.id}>
        <li>
          <form className="relative" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {props.level === 2 && <span className="absolute h-full ml-2 border border-gray-100 -left-20 border-left-2"></span>}      
            <span className="absolute w-8 h-6 border border-t-0 border-b-2 border-l-2 border-r-0 border-gray-100 -left-7 top-3 rounded-bl-xl -top-2"></span>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between w-full pb-3 pr-10 space-x-2">
              <button aria-label="Chris Chilcoat's Timeline" role="link" tabIndex="0" className="z-20 flex-shrink-0 block border-2 border-white rounded-full hover:bg-black focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-600 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-opacity-60">
                <img className="w-6 h-6 bg-gray-300 rounded-full hover:opacity-90" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt=""></img>
              </button>
              <input type="text" className="flex-1 px-3 py-1 text-sm font-light text-left text-gray-700 placeholder-gray-500 bg-gray-100 rounded-full shadow-inner hover:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-600 focus:ring-offset-2 text-md focus:ring-opacity-60" placeholder="Write a reply..."></input>
            </div>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
```

```
  const handleAddComment = (id, prop, val) => {   
    let temp_state = [...comments]; // 1. Make a shallow copy of the array.
    let new_element = { 'id': comments.length, 
                        'name': 'Jim Brown', 
                        'likes': 0, 
                        'replyVisible': false, 
                        'message': 'this was added via handleAddComment', 
                        'avatarURL': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  
                        'imageUrl': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463453091185-61582044d556?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=8&w=1024&h=1024&q=80'}
                      // 2. Create new element to be added.
    temp_state.push(new_element); // 3. Put it back into our array.
    setComments(temp_state); // 4. Set the state to our new copy
  }
```

Any insight would be of great help.

Comment: What makes you think it is not updating? If you are using it inside `handleToggleReplyInput`, it's possible it's not finished updating yet (since setting state is asynchronous)

Comment: Use `useEffect` with dependency array equals to `[stateName]` and try consoling your state inside that. And also post your whole code I don't see state variables in the above code.

Comment: I guess thats possible, Its just i can see my temp_state being created correctly and then when it gets to the setComments(temp_state) nothing happens. No update. How can i tell if this is not finished updating?

Comment: Ok, let me get a  jsfiddle for you guys.

Comment: This is a copy of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/chrischilcoat/fqs02pvk/